# Hyper-V not pre-installed in my win 10 pro laptop

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

My win-10 pro has no hyper-v pre-installed as I see nothing in program and features.How can I get it installed in my laptop? 
P.S. Hyper-v system requirements is matched by my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PowerShell.  Docs with several installation options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install#install-hyper-v-with-powershell)

PowerShell command (run as Administrator):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Comment: Thanks.It helped..!!